# Doctrine: extending entity class

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

I would like to extend Entity\Base classes, how to do this in Doctrine 2.1? My research showed that whenever someone encounters the problem with doing this he switches to Doctrine 1.2 :)n I am using yaml configuration

Comment: why do you want to extend it?

Comment: I would like to create a new class that extends the base on, something like User extends UserBase. Actually right now all base classes are in Entities/Base so I would like to create new classes in Entities and they will extend Entities/Base classes

Comment: @jaro I would like to follow pattern from Doctrine 1.2 that I have base classes and normal classes, i extend base classes to be able to write my own custom methods. The problem is that the base classes are auto-generated and I do not want to lose code everytime I change something in the model.

Comment: could you post a code example of what you want to achieve maybe?

Comment: @jere already fixed, instead of making ClassModel extends ClassBase I have made ClassBase extends ClassModel

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Doctrine 2.X Entities work as POPOs (Plain Old PHP Objects).
To achieve extending correctly, Doctrine enforces you to use a concept from JPA called Mapped Super Classes.
The idea is pretty simple. Whenever you want to have a base class and want your entities to extend from it (I'm not talking about inheritance at DB level), all you need to do is create your Base class as a MappedSuperClass.

Here is an example: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Thanks

Comment: I have done something similar, thank for the effort, even though the problem has been solved couple of days ago I will mark your answer as right anyway

Comment: You could have posted the solution, you know. The whole purpose of this community is to help eachother.

Comment: @NikolaPetkanski you are 100% right, and you can observe that I do answer my own question if I find solution.

Comment: Today's living [doctrine 2.6 reference to Mapped Superclasses](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses)

Answer (score 13):

Here the solution from Guilherme Blanco link. I like to have a posted solution instead of a link which eventually could no longer work in future:

```php
<?php
/** @MappedSuperclass */
class MappedSuperclassBase
{
    /** @Column(type="integer") */
    protected $mapped1;

    /** @Column(type="string") */
    protected $mapped2;

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="MappedSuperclassRelated1")
     * @JoinColumn(name="related1_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $mappedRelated1;

    // ... more fields and methods
}

/** @Entity */
class EntitySubClass extends MappedSuperclassBase
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") */
    private $id;

    /** @Column(type="string") */
    private $name;

    // ... more fields and methods
}
```

Comment: You are a prophet ;) Thanks