# Subclass Doctrine 2 entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, subclass

I am trying to subclass a Doctrine 2 entity to add a bunch of "helper" functions I'd like to use.

For example, this is my entity:

```
namespace Project\Entity;
class Product
{
    private $name;
    private $idProductCategory;
}
```

Mapping is done via XML files.

Then, I try to extend it:

```
namespace Project\Entity;
class ProductJSON extends Product {
    public function toJSON() {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

When I try to use this object in Doctrine:

```
$a = $entityManager->getRepository('\Project\Entity\ProductJSON');
```

I get the "*No mapping file found named Project.Entity.ProductJSON.dcm.xml*" error.
Which is perfectly right, because I do not want any additional mapping.

I've extensively read Doctrine docs and about Mapped Super Classes ([Doctrine: extending entity class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943615/doctrine-extending-entity-class)), but as far as I understand that is for extending Entities in a DB-sense.

I don't care about the database/mapping, I just want to extend entities PHP-wise to use the objects seamlessy in my application.

How to achieve this goal?

Comment: Is just your example wrong or are you actually missing the `extends Product` statement?

Comment: Just missing in the example. Edited thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a subclass to add additional methods. Just add the methods to your entity class - Doctrine will just ignore them because there is no mapping information attached to them.

E.g.

```
class Product
{
    private $name;
    private $idProductCategory;

    /* ... */

    public function toJSON() {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Comment: But what if I migrate and re-generate entities? I'd lose all the changes I've done, right?

Comment: What do you mean by "migrate and re-generate"? Usually Doctrine generates the DB schema from your entity class code, not the other way around - but maybe I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: As stated, I am using XML for the schema or "data mapping", so if I change that schema, migrate the DB to it and regenerate entities (`doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./path-to-src`, `doctrine:generate:entities`) I'd lose what I've done...